# Dropdownlist used as Datasource, then use Foreach to get data from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to iterate through a combobox that has a DataSource set as below

```
var things = new Dictionary<int, string>();
cboOrg1.DisplayMember = "Value";
cboOrg1.ValueMember = "Key";
cboOrg1.DataSource = new BindingSource(things, null);
```

Then I try to get the data in the list, as I try to use o I don't have the option to use select the value member. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
foreach (var o in cboOrg1.Items)
{
    o.
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `cboOrg1`? And what actually framework you're using - is it `winforms` or `asp.net`? Both of them in tags but they are pretty different frameworks.

Comment: Sorry, it is a combobox not a dropdownlist. Winforms not asp.net

Comment: It would be easier to just move the `things` declaration to the form scope level, then you can just access the list without caring about the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will declare type for your loop variable explicitly as `KeyValuePair<int, string>` (according to data type of your dictionary being used as binding source) - you will be able to use `o.Value` property and so on.

Like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> o in cboOrg1.Items)
{
    var x = o.Value;
}
```